# dd to clone 2 hard drives with 2 OSes and an encrypted partition

Tags: backup, multi-boot, grub, disk-encryption, dd

So, I have a question with this complex back-up process. My computer has a 32GB SSD, where Ubuntu 13.10 and all programs that run on that system are located. There is only one partition on that drive, namely `/dev/sdb1`, an `ext4` partition. Then there is another 1TB HDD, where there are 4 primary partitions:

```
/dev/sda1    ext4    Data drive
/dev/sda2    NTFS    Data drive
/dev/sda3    NTFS    Windows 8.1
/dev/sda4    ext4    TrueCrypt Encrypted Partition
```

I want to have a solution, if at all possible, that uses `dd` from a Live CD, that can backup both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, onto a 4TB external HDD, and I want to keep the GRUB boot loader, and all other information, so that when the image is restored in case of virus or other attacks, such as hard drive failures, I can boot into both Ubuntu and Windows. What command should I use? I was thinking of this:

Let's pretend that `/dev/sdd` is the external hard drive, and I have 2 proposed solutions:

Solution 1:

- Partition `dev/sdd` into `/dev/sdd1` and `/dev/sdd2`
- `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd1` and `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdd2`

Solution 2:

- Partition `/dev/sdd` into `/dev/sddX` where `1 <= X <= 5`
- `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdd1` and `dd if=/dev/sdaX of=/dev/sdd(X + 1)` until `X = 5`.

Is this a good solution for my purposes, or is there a better solution?

Oh, yeah, a drive is allowed to have a maximum of 4 partitions! I suddenly remembered! So what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this plan is correct, for many reasons: you cannot/should not *dd* a device to a partition, you have forgotten to introduce offsets in your dd commands so that you will be overwriting your data, *dd* will copy all blanks, and leave many blanks on the target HDD, the boot information will be lost/corrupted, it is likely you have ms-dos partition tables on your disks while the 4TB disk demands a GPT partition table to be able to address all of its volume, and so on.

I would go piecewise. Boot from a live distro, like Ubuntu (choose *Try Ubuntu without installing*...), open a terminal and install *gparted*,

```
 sudo apt-get install gparted.
```

1) use gparted to create a GPT on the 4TB disk, *i.e.* a partition table of the new format which is different from the ms-dos partition table, then ...

2) create partitions of identical dimensions and filesystem types to those of your two used disks.

3) Add, if you wish, other partitions in the remaining area of the 4TB HDD.

4) Now you can clone partitions. With all of your disks unmounted, issue:

```
  sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdc1 bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror
  sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sdc2 bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror
```

and so on.

Now the copy is complete, but it cannot possibly boot. Still on your live, download and install Boot-Repair following the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). You will be asked on which disk you will want to place Grub, and which disks you wish to consider. **If**, as you said, you need the 4TB HDD as a back-up, then you should exclude your two current disks from examination, and instruct Boot-Repair to use only the 4TB HDD. Follow the standard instructions, they are more than sufficient under most circumstances.

Now reboot from the 4TB HDD, to check that everything works. At this point, if there is any problem, it concerns only booting off a newly minted disk, a minor undertaking.

Comment: Can you clarify why there could be MS-DOS tables on the internal hard drives? I actually had to "jailbreak" into my laptop and ended up wiping out everything a few months ago. I wiped out both drives, put Ubuntu 13.04 on, Windows no longer existed for a few months. Then, I put Windows 8 on (after Ubuntu), remember, I used `GParted`to format all drives. So, both the SSD and the HDD have GPTs in them. I boot into a GRUB menu, and if I boot into Windows from there, Windows Boot Loader will pop up, asking what Windows I want to boot (I have Windows 7 VHD-install as well).

Comment: @user2213307 No, there does not **have** to be an old-style ms-dos partition table. I thought there might be, but you clarified there is not. Still, the rest of my argument stands... It cannot be done the way you wish to do it.

Comment: Something extremely interesting happened. In Windows 8, the drive is recognized to be an NTFS drive, but in Ubuntu, it is recognized as unallocated space. Does this mean that the (4TB external) HDD has an MS-DOS table and needs to be formatted to have GPT so that it can be read in Ubuntu?

Comment: @user2213307 It looks like you do not have ntfs-3g. sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g. Does Ubuntu now recognize the ntfs partition?

Comment: I do have ntfs-3g (hence I can access Windows partitions in Ubuntu).

Comment: Oh, now I understand. The only way that your solution can work is if I merge the 2 NTFS partitions (i.e. put the contents of the NTFS data drive into the Windows 8 drive and then merge the NTFS partitions).

Answer (score 4):

```
mkdir /somewhere
mount /dev/sdd /somewhere
dd conv=noerror if=/dev/sda of=/somewhere/entire-sda.img
dd conv=noerror if=/dev/sdb of=/somewhere/entire-sdb.img
```

This does have the side effect of lumping all partitions on one drive into 1 file.  However everything is preserved.  However, dd is not a space efficient way of handling it as it clones gigs of free space.

Comment: 'pv' can be better in place of 'dd' as it states progress.

Comment: This approach has a couple of benefits: (1) it allows you to use the modification date/times of the backup image files to track when the backups occurred, and (2) it makes it easier to see when a backup failed to complete (because the image file size will be less than it should be).